# Visual Studio 2012 + SQL Server 2012 Express table deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have a big problem. I am running Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Express.

I made a connection in VS to the SQL Server successfully, and then proceeded to create a table. I create the table and click the `Update` button. Now, in the Server Explorer the table shows with all its components as it should, however, the tables get deleted after I shut down my computer (if I just close VS and re-open it the tables are there) so I have to re-create them all the time.

Anybody knows anything about this? It's extremely frustrating having to re-create the tables after each shutdown of my computer.